# mongoengine get method does not work for id with string value

Tags: python-3.x, primary-key, mongoengine, identifier

I have specified `mongoengine` model class with `_id` field as a `StringField`:

```
class Store(DynamicDocument):
    _id = StringField(primary_key=True, min_length=1)
```

And now when I query document by `_id` field I get document properly:

[image: get by _id]

I can get it by `pk` too:

[image]

but I cannot get it by `id`:

[image: get by id]

As you can see at the first screen there's `id` and `pk` fields initialized successfully. So I just can't make it out why `mongoengine` behaves like this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare your "_id" as "id":

```
class Store(DynamicDocument):
    id = StringField(primary_key=True, min_length=1)
```